# Create a fully functional desktop shortcut(can be found in "Show applications", be added to Favorites, and running window combined with anchored icon)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

Seems a trivial task but making it work completely really is not simple. Nowadays in Gnome on Ubuntu, how to create a desktop shortcut correctly, so that it

- can be found in "Show Applications" in Gnome
- would show "Add to Favorite" when right-clicked and be added to Favorite
- shown in a combined way on the dash when running, so that the anchored favorite icon is combined with the running app window

?

For example, for Intellij IDEA, this is not easy task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things to align: `WM_CLASS` vs desktop filename, and `StartWMClass` vs executable name. **Even though both have `WM` in name, they have different values.** That caused me a lot of confusion.

1. Run your app, run `xprop` and click on the app window. Search for `WM_CLASS` line. For Intellij IDEA, it's `jetbrains-idea-ce`. Take only one value from the two.

```bash
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "jetbrains-idea-ce", "jetbrains-idea-ce"
```

2. Create a `.desktop` file named after it, `jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop`.
3. Put these lines into it:

```bash
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Intellij IDEA
Exec=/opt/idea-IC-211.7142.45/bin/idea.sh
Icon=/opt/idea-IC-211.7142.45/bin/idea.svg
StartupWMClass=idea.sh
```

Notice that filename matches `WM_CLASS` line value, **but `StartupWMClass` should instead match the executable name, `idea.sh`.** Another example is `gnome-connection-manager`, where you put the `.py` filename, not the whole command.

```bash
[Desktop Entry]
...
Exec=python3 /opt/gnome-connection-manager-1.2.1/gnome_connection_manager.py
...
Name[en]=Gnome Connection Manager
StartupWMClass=gnome_connection_manager.py
```

This step will combine the favorite anchored icon with running app window.

4. Put your `jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop` into `/usr/share/applications`. Then, you can find it in `Show Applications`. But now if you right click it, you cannot add it to favorite yet.
5. Put it now also into `~/.local/share/applications`. Then it can be added to favorite now.

I don't know why this has to be this complicated.

Comment: +1 Can confirm. On ubuntu 22.04, I was following these steps for a desktop entry for php storm. The only thing I was missing was the .desktop filename. I had it wrong, just php-storm was not allowing me the option to add to favorites. 

Once I ran xprop on it, and used the suggested name from WM_CLASS, it all worked like a charm.